How do I keep my rear axle from falling out of the dropouts?
My Ebike rear hub axle keep falling out on the dropouts.  The first time it ended up chewing up my wire so I replaced the motor. I ordered some torque arms and new hardware and I hooked it all up last night and as soon as I turned it, it fell out again. Not sure if I’m doing the washers incorrectly or I don’t know, but my dropouts aren’t completely laid up. They’re not bad.


 Stock photos from https://smlrobicycle.com/products/smlro-xdc600-electric-bike-300w-500w-1000w 

Welcome. What kind of axle do you have? Can you show a photo? I also suggest to take the [tour].

Also, is it a conversion kit (if so, what make/model/power?) or was it built as an ebike originally (if so, what make/model?)

It is an smlro xdc600 i haven’t made any changes to it

I've added some stock photos of this bike from the maker's website.  Could you please use [edit] to add some clear and well lit photos of your bike showing the damage?   Perhaps one with the wheel out of the dropouts too ?  Thanks

Do you know the correct order ? I keep reading different ? Anti spin washers on inside or outside

Can you show us the photo of your asssembly? With the washers as you are putting there and everything. We need to see the details.

The manufacturer's website is heavy on photos and light on specs; the photos don't show much detail but do show variation.    We can probably help figure this out but need detailed photos of the rear axle/dropout region on the model you actually have

I’m sorry I’m trying lol I’ve never used this website so I’m trying to add photos.
